# Posting embedded output using tabulate and Discord Rewrite

Tags: python, embed, discord.py, tabulate

I have a Discord bot where I'm attempting to send some output in an `embed` using the `tabulate` library. When I send the message using ``` it's formatted as such

[image: Example]

If I send the message embedded with  ```

[image: Example2]

If I send the message embedded without the ```

[image: Example3]

I've tried consulting the `tabulate` docs, and noticed the `stralign` `colalign` and other formatting options, but nothing I've used has worked so far

Without ```

```py
output = ("\n\n" + tabulate(entries, tablefmt="plain", headers=["#", "Points", "Level", "Player","ID"]))
```

With ```

````py
output = ("```" + "\n\n" + tabulate(entries, tablefmt="plain", headers=["#", "Points", "Level", "Player","ID"]) + "```")
````

My goal is to prevent the embedded message from wrapping to a new line if the length of the row is too long. I kind of achieve that when I don't use ```, but the issue then is the columns aren't aligning with the headers.

Comment: What is your problem??

Comment: I just realized, I forgot to clarify. See the edited post.